# How to Enable/Disable a IsEnabled/IsHitTestVisible Property of a Checkbox with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, checkbox

I'm trying to Enable/Disable a checkbox being checked. Our application uses MVVM, is being develop with c# WPF, and no code-behind. Just MVVM and Binding.
I'm trying to do using PropertyChanged, but no luck. All other fields works just fine, except this one.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ct:DataGridExtended Name="dtgProfiles" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" FrozenColumnCount="2" Margin="-1,23,-1,-1" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding RightProfiles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding RightProfilesSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ResourcesSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="4">
        <ct:DataGridExtended.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,2,1,1"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsEditing, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding RightProfile.Name}" />
    </ct:DataGridExtended.Columns>
</ct:DataGridExtended>
```

You can see there, i've set the IsHitTestVisible to my IsEditing property. This property notifies if user is in edit mode or view mode. My problem is, this is the only field than Binding IsEditing doesn't work.

Being more exactly (maybe there's another way to do that): While in ViewMode, i can't let user updates nothing in my Grid, including TextBlocks and Checkbox. I could block my entire grid using IsHitTestVisible={"Binding IsEditing}", but with this, I also blocks my ScrollBar. And the user is allowed to scroll this grid.

How I can do this? It's burning my head already.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "grid" are you referring to "datagridextended"? If not, can you post the rest of your code here?

Comment: Yes, grid i mean a DataGridExtended. It's a DataGrid but i've customized it (it inherits from original DataGrid).

Comment: Your DataGrid's "IsReadOnly" property is set to true, isn't this enough for what you want?

Comment: No. Again, the user is only allowed to change my checkbox inside that grid if he's in Alter Mode. If he's in ViewMode, Everything in that grid, except my ScrollViewer (or Scroll Bar) can be selectable The problem is, if i set IsReadOnly to true, my checkbox still allows user to change his value when in View Mode.